# How to have the program wait for input before proceding

Tags: java

I am having a problem where my program is scanning for two different inputs at the same time.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Person {

public static void main(String[] args){
Person p1 = new Person();

System.out.println("1: Add Person");
System.out.println("2: Delete Person");
System.out.println();
System.out.print("Please make a selection: ");
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
int selection = keyboard.nextInt();

switch(selection){
    case 1: 
        System.out.print("Please enter name: ");
        String name = keyboard.nextLine();
        p1.addPerson(name);
        break;
    }
}
public Person(){

}

public void addPerson(String name){

    int day, month, year;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter date of birth in the format dd mm yyyy: ");
    day = keyboard.nextInt();
    month = keyboard.nextInt();
    year = keyboard.nextInt();
}
}
```

This is the output:

```
1: Add Person
2: Delete Person

Please make a selection: 1
Please enter name: Please enter date of birth in the format dd mm yyyy:
```

The program does not wait for the name to be entered, how do i fix this?

Comment: Try keyboard.next() when reading the string name instead of nextLine();

Comment: @chad if you consider your question answered, please accept most helpful answer.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is when you do `nextInt()` it scans an integer, but not the new line character(`\n`), so when you call `nextLine()` it just consumes `\n` you typed when was doing selection and returns empty string.

Several ways to fix it:

First is to call `nextLine()` after `nextInt`. To fix your code you would do this:

```
int selection = keyboard.nextInt();
keyboard.nextLine();
```

Second option is to call `nextLine()` but when you need int wrap in in `Integer.parseInt()`. So, for example, your selection would look like:

```
int selection = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine());
```

Other option would be to use `next()` instead of `nextLine`, however, **this approach wouldn't work** if `name` contains spaces.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `keyboard.next()`

From the java docs:

> next(): Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner.

This is what `keyboard.nextLine()` does:

> nextLine(): Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped.